# Put some text next to Bootstrap 3 input

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have got the Bootstrap 3 code below:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3 control-label">
        <label>Surname:</label>
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-9">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname"><span>!</span>
</div>
```

And I need to show the exclamation mark next to the input, but it is always on the new line. How to put it nex to the input, please?

Thanks

Comment: I responded here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18404003/label-on-the-left-side-instead-above-an-input-field/33974788 regards!

Answer (score 4):

Use this code, it works

```
   <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-3 control-label">
            <label>Surname:</label>
        </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <div class="input-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname"><span class="input-group-addon">!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried that, but (and I am sorry that I didnt mention it in the question) I cannot use this for checkboxes or textareas.

Answer (score 2):

If your using a `form-inline` it will work like this..

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Surname:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="surname"> !
  </div>
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/119169

Comment: Thanks, I'm using form horizontal.